# redirect on submit button depending on option

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, submit

So i am writing a code with a drop down list and a submit button. It looks like this in my CaseType.jsp file :

```
<title>Case Type Selection</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CaseType.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
Please select the case that applies
<br><br><br>


<form action="">
<select id ="caseType" name="caseType">
<option value="PromoAttr">Promotion Attribute Change</option>
<option value="PromoOrder">Promotion Approval Order Change</option>
<option value="DefAppr">Change Default Approver on Promotion</option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
<br><button onclick="caseSelect()" align="right">Submit</button></form>
<br><a href="C:\Users\apay\workspace\PDFproj\WebContent\Help.jsp">Help</a>
</form>
```

What I want to be able to do is click the submit button and take in the value of which option was chosen and redirect to a different JSP page depending on the button. In my search on these questions I have only found solutions using PHP pages. and window.location or document.location doesn't seem to be working for me. This is my .js file for caseType:

```
function caseSelect()
{
    var select = document.getElementById('caseType').value;
    switch(select)
    {
    case "PromoAttr":
      //open up form for Promotion Attribute Changes
        alert("Promo attr works");
        document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/PDFproj/generalCase.jsp";

      break;
    case "PromoOrder":
      //open up form for Promotion approval order change
        alert("Promo order works");
        document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/PDFproj/generalCase.jsp";
      break;
    case "DefAppr":
      //open up form for Changing default approver on promotion
        alert("Default Approval works");
        document.location.href="http://localhost:8080/PDFproj/generalCase.jsp";
          break;
    default:


    }
    return false;

}
```

Right now they are all leading to a general case page because I have not yet received the details on what each case form will have to look like, so this is just a prototype. But in the end, they will all have their own separate forms that have to be filled out and submitted.

Please let me know how I can do this. I am interested in javascript or jquery answers. Thank you.

Comment: try using `window.location = url` or `window.navigate(url)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to take a value from one page to another, you could add that value to the url as a query string, and once you get to that page have your javascript grab that value off the url and parse it into your code. Set the parameter like so:

```
case "PromoAttr":
    alert("Promo attr works");
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/PDFproj/generalCase.jsp";

    location.href = url + "?selectedVal=PromoAttr";
    break;
//Repeat for other cases, substituting "PromoAttr" for the selected value.
```

Then in your next page you can check to see if there are any query strings attached to your url, and if there is, parse it off and use it as you wish.

Comment: Although your answer was helpful, that is not exactly what I was looking for. But I think i could possibly edit your answer to give me what I was looking for. generalCase is just a temporary case but I will soon have options for different cases leading to different pages. So would I just make the var url the url up to /PDFproj/ then have the case option saved as a variable and add it in later?

Comment: Yep, exactly. It really depends on how you'll be needing the option that was selected. If you're just redirecting to a different url depending on the selected option, then you just change the url in each case after /PDFproj/, just like you said. And to redirect, it is location.href = url + "page-to-go-to";